# mysql Select with where condition based on count

Tags: mysql

I have query that looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
WHERE `waarde3` = 'Oke' 
    OR `waarde4` = 'Oke' 
    AND `config` = 'XMLserver'
```

Now I want add special condition if the count of `waarde2 != 0` then condition is `waarde2 = 'int'` else `waarde2 = 'ext'`

this is what I tried:

try 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
WHERE `waarde3` = 'Oke'
    OR `waarde4` = 'Oke' 
    AND `config` = 'XMLserver' 
    AND `waarde2`= 
    (
        (
            SELECT count(*) 
            FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
            WHERE `config` = 'XMLserver' AND`waarde2`= 'int' AND 
                (`waarde3` = 'Oke' 
                    OR `waarde4` = 'Oke'
                )

        ) > 0
        ,'int'
        ,'ext'
    )
```

try2:

```
if (SELECT count(*) FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` WHERE `waarde2`= 'int' AND (`waarde4` = 'Oke' OR `waarde3`= 'Oke')) > 0 
   THEN
       SELECT count(*) FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` WHERE `waarde2`= 'int' AND (`waarde4` = 'Oke' OR `waarde3`= 'Oke')
else
       SELECT count(*) FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` WHERE `waarde2`= 'ext' AND (`waarde4` = 'Oke' OR `waarde3`= 'Oke')
   END
```

What am doing wrong ?

some clarification in my criteria for the query for the main query

The selecetion criteria must be:
1.  config = 'XMLserver'
2.  Waarde3 or waarde4  or both mus be 'Oke'

query for without waard2 as criteria would be :

```
SELECT * FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
WHERE `config` = 'XMLserver' 
   AND`waarde2`= 'int' 
   AND (
         `waarde3` = 'Oke' 
          OR 
          `waarde4` = 'Oke'
       )
```

To determent the value of waarde2 my selection requerments are:

1. config = 'XMLserver'
2. waarde2 = int
3. Waarde3 or waarde4  or both must be 'Oke'

The count query would then be :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
WHERE `config` = 'XMLserver' 
   AND`waarde2`= 'int' 
   AND (
         `waarde3` = 'Oke' 
         OR 
         `waarde4` = 'Oke'
       )
```

If the count of this selection is 0 then waarde = ext
If the count of this selection is lager then 0 waarde = int

Comment: First thing I noticed that you want to add condition waarde2' != 0 however you have >0 condition in try1 and try2

Comment: What do you mean by `if the count of waarde2 != 0`? `waarde2` is a column. Do you want to count if there is at list one time `waarde2 = 'int'`?

Comment: Note that you need brackets to make your `OR` work the way you want it to. ie `A OR B AND C` is parsed as `A OR (B AND C)` not `(A OR B) AND C`

Comment: I changed the try 1 but it still doen't work
The selecetion criteria must be:
1.  config = 'XMLserver'
2.  Waarde3 or waarde4  or both mus be 'Oke'

Comment: I just edited the question hoping that that makes it more clear what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the sollution and it is :

```
SELECT * FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
WHERE `config` = 'XMLserver' 
AND (
    `waarde3` = 'Oke'
    OR
    `waarde4` = 'Oke'
    )
    AND
    CASE 
    (
        select COUNT(*) from bas_HCCxmlSettings
        where 
        `config` ='XMLserver'
        AND
        `waarde2` = 'int'
        AND
        (
            `waarde3` = 'Oke'
            OR
            `waarde4` = 'Oke'
            )
        )
        WHEN 0 
        THEN `waarde2` = 'ext'
        ELSE `waarde2` = 'int'
        END
```

Comment: Please award yourself the green tick.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * FROM `bas_HCCxmlSettings` 
WHERE `waarde3` = 'Oke' 
OR `waarde4` = 'Oke' 
AND `config` = 'XMLserver'
AND waarde2 = (CASE COUNT(waarde2)
               WHEN 0 THEN 'ext' 
               ELSE 'INT' 
               END)
```

Tell me if it works !!!!

Comment: it doesn't invalide use of group function